# Navbar code from Bootstrap Components not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to Bootstrap Framework and I am trying to run Navbar from the components of Boostrap and it is not working. I checked the same on mobile screen and the toggle button is not working and neither are the drop down menus working for me. Could someone plz point out the problem? It is unusual because I took the code right from the official website so there is no chance of the same going wrong, but I am somehow not able to locate the error. I have checked the links and they are working for other components except this particular one.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Navbar</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="boot/css/mystyle.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="boot/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="boot/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="boot/js/boostrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="boot/js/docs.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure bootstrap file is linked with the html?

Comment: Yes, perfectly sure.

Comment: Goto http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/
And click Download Bootstrap
From the zip copy css and js folder

Comment: @SaifUrRahman I have done that already and added the files again, checked the `view source` too. I guess, there is some other problem.

Comment: What do you get when you click the bootstrap css link from the `view-source`?

Comment: I simply go to the related files. They all open up in a new tab when I click their links.

Comment: Strange behavior.

Comment: @SaifUrRahman What does `<span class="icon-bar"></span>` in the toggle stand for? Why do we use these 3 span tags?

Comment: They are for the hamburger icon on mobile view. Try deleting one or two and see what happens on mobile view.

Comment: Thanks! And supposedly we use `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">` to collapse menu formed by clicking the button in mobile view?

Comment: That div just encapsulates the form items. `<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">` this is the button that we use to toggle the menu.

Comment: Then why do we use `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">` class? Any idea and where can I get detailed info on the classes used by bootstrap and their utilities?

Comment: To style the navbar. You can search on google each classname.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the help!

Comment: I recommend reading the bootstrap docs of each component that you use.

Comment: Off course, I'll do that, thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works correctly, but make sure your includes `bootstrap` files exists

**check this**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Navbar</title>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="boot/js/boostrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="boot/js/docs.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll just check out the Bootstrap files, although, I think they were working.

Comment: @Don'tDownvoteMe that means you were not sure about those files.

Comment: @SaifUrRahman The guy just answered and attached CDN's, I will check if the CDN's are working for me too, but I am not sure. Other components are working for me using the files that i have attached.

Comment: @Don'tDownvoteMe Have you tried using `./boot` instead of `boot`?

Comment: @Don'tDownvoteMe I mean `href="/boot/css/bootstrap.min.css"` instead of `href="boot/css/bootstrap.min.css"`. Having a `/` before `boot`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174071/discussion-between-saif-ur-rahman-and-dontdownvoteme).

Comment: Your original file seems to work on my local system.

Comment: @Don'tDownvoteMe To check whether the css file is attached or not you can `view-source` from the `html` from the browser then visit the `css` link attached there.

Comment: @SaifUrRahman Just checked and the files are attached. Don't understand why the files are not working when the CDN is working just fine.